# Swift 2: @objc protocol and enum array

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift2, protocols

I have an enumeration defined as follow:

```
@objc enum MyEnum: Int {
   case Case1, Case2
}
```

and the following protocol:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
   func myFunc(myData: [MyEnum])
}
```

now the protocol throws the following error:

```
 Method cannot be a member of a @objc protocol because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Why this works:

```
func MyFunc(myData: MyEnum)
```

but throws error with the array?

I thought of passing an array of Int and then convert it back to enum but i don't like it very much. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it shouldn't work because an Objective-C array should contain only pointers, and an enum of `Int` doesn't contain pointers.

You can try something like this

```
@objc enum MyEnum: Int {
    case Case1, Case2

    var numberValue : NSNumber {

        get {

            return NSNumber(
                integer: self.rawValue
            )
        }
    }
}

@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    func myFunc(myData: [NSNumber])
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right I didn't think that NSArray must contain only pointers. As for the resolution, I moved the for loop outside the function instead of making the transformation outside the function and then again inside the function